# React Font Awesome - Icon code \f00d does not show

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome

I am trying to add an icon to an existing project who already used icons. I need this particular one with the code '\f00d'. I can see it in `node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css` as following:

`.fa-remove:before, .fa-close:before, .fa-times:before { content: "\f00d"; }`

However it is not working with any of those clases ( other icons work, like `.fa-window-close:before { content: "\f2d3"; }` )

This is how I am using it:

`<i className="fas fa-close" onClick={onClose} />`

Comment: what is the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using Font Awesome v.5.0 or lower, in this version fa-times regular is only available in FA5 Pro. I would urge you to upgrade your Font Awesome package to v.6 and following their guidlines for using Font Awesome in React projects. [Font Awesome React Docs](https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/use-with/react/). There you could use, https://fontawesome.com/icons/xmark?s=solid. But regular is still only available to Pro users.

Comment: I have used fa-times and seems like this one is working. Thank you.